Parsing contents of tcolorbox inside parbox

I want result similar to the above, except that I want it be done without explictly using \parbox
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{book}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{empty}

\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
% BEGIN_FOLD

    % Horizontal
    \geometry{textwidth=5cm, marginparsep=3.5mm, marginparwidth=5cm, bindingoffset=0mm, includemp=true}
    
    \geometry{showframe=false, twoside=false}

% END_FOLD

\usepackage[x11names]{xcolor}

\usepackage{ragged2e}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\usepackage{marginnote}

% =========== Framed boxes packages ===========    
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{skins,breakable}
% BEGIN_FOLD    

\tcbset{MarginNote/.style=%
    {
        size=minimal,
        colframe=white, colback=Ivory1,
        opacityframe=0, opacityback=0.75,
        box align=base,
        nobeforeafter,
        width=\linewidth,
    }
}%

% END_FOLD

\begin{document}
    
    \noindent%
    \smash{\rlap{\rule{\dimexpr \linewidth + \marginparsep + \marginparwidth \relax}{0.1pt}}}%
    Text Text%
    \marginnote{\tcbox[MarginNote]{\parbox[t]{\linewidth}{\RaggedRight The quick brown fox}}}
    
\end{document}


How do the picture and the code relate?

why not simply \foo{some text}  defined as \newcommand\foo[1]{ \tcbox[MarginNote]{\parbox[t]{\linewidth}{#1}}}

@campa. I modified the code to produce the image above

@DavidCarlisle. This is a possible solution, but I want to be able to use the autocompletion provided by TeXstudio for tcolorbox

If you use a tcolorbox, you don't need a parbox to set the width:
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{book}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{empty}

\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
% BEGIN_FOLD

    % Horizontal
    \geometry{textwidth=5cm, marginparsep=3.5mm, marginparwidth=5cm, bindingoffset=0mm, includemp=true}
    
    \geometry{showframe=false, twoside=false}

% END_FOLD

\usepackage[x11names]{xcolor}

\usepackage{ragged2e}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\usepackage{marginnote}

% =========== Framed boxes packages ===========    
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{skins,breakable}
% BEGIN_FOLD    

\tcbset{MarginNote/.style=%
    {
        size=minimal,
        colframe=white, colback=Ivory1,
        opacityframe=0, opacityback=0.75,
        box align=base,
        nobeforeafter,
        width=\linewidth,
        before upper=\strut,
    }
}%

% END_FOLD

\begin{document}
    
    \noindent%
    \smash{\rlap{\rule{\dimexpr \linewidth + \marginparsep + \marginparwidth \relax}{0.1pt}}}%
    Text Text%
    \marginnote{\begin{tcolorbox}[MarginNote]The quick brown fox The quick brown fox\end{tcolorbox}}
    
\end{document}


